# I am trying to configure the configuration of the web catalog so that the products

Tags: orocommerce

I am trying to configure the configuration of the web catalog so that the products page remains as my main page. I did the following steps but I did not get any result.

1. go to Marketing / Web Catalogs
2. click on "Edit Content Tree" for the chosen web catalog
3. And change the default content variant for the root tree node. By default, it's set to
   the "System Page" - "Oro Frontend Root". Set the "System Page Route" to "Oro Product
   Frontend Prduct Index

I create a ticket and it asks me if I have consumer messages running, how can I verify this?

Comment: Hi Diego, please stop duplicating questions for every further clarification. We can continue discussions in comments of previous question. Or, you can join our Slack chat and discuss questions there in threads: https://bitly.com/oro-slack .

Comment: Hello, I have already left comments with doubts, but they have not been answered, so I am forced to ask a new question.

Answer (score 0):

The message consumer is one of the required background processes for OroCommerce applications.

Here it's mentioned in the installation guide:
https://doc.oroinc.com/backend/setup/installation/#configure-and-run-required-background-processes

The more detailed reference is available here:
https://doc.oroinc.com/backend/mq/consumer/

You should be able to find these articles with Google. Like https://www.google.com/search?q=orocommerce+message+consumer